# Migrating Classic ASP from Windows server 2003 to 2008 R2

Tags: windows, vbscript, asp-classic

I have been asked to look at the feasibility of migrating an ASP app from Windows 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2.

> **Old setup:**
>
> ASP Classic Hosted on: Windows Server 2003 DB: SQL Server 2000
>
> **Proposed new setup:**
>
> ASP Classic Hosted on: Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS: 7 DB: SQL Server
>   2008

Ideally the app should be re-written in ASP.NET, but the company doesn't have the budget for this right now.

**Questions**

- Would it be possible to host Classic ASP built on Windows 2003 w/ IIS 6 on a Windows 2008 R2 w/ IIS 7.5 environment?
- What steps can be taken to successfully migrate the application and database from the old environment to the new environment.?

Comment: Yes, it is very much feasible, but unfortunately this question is too vague for Stack Overflow. I recommend that you narrow it down to specific problems you might be facing.

Comment: Thank you I might come up with more question when the project will start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be possible to host Classic ASP built on Windows 2003 w/ IIS
>   6 on a Windows 2008 R2 w/ IIS 7.5 environment?

Classic ASP can be hosted on Windows 2008 and 2012.  As of IIS 7, Classic ASP is no longer enabled by default. See this [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis).

**How to enable Classic ASP module in Windows 2008**

1. Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Server
   Manager.
2. In the Server Manager hierarchy pane, expand Roles, and
   then click Web Server (IIS).
3. In the Web Server (IIS) pane, scroll to the Role Services section, and then click Add Role Services.
4. On the Select Role Services page of the Add Role Services Wizard, select
   ASP.

> What steps can be taken to successfully migrate the application and
>   database from the old environment to the new environment?

- **32 bit vs 64 bit components** - 32 bit dlls do not work in 64 bit application pool.  Make sure your Application Pool is set accordingly.
- Classic ASP uses "Classic .NET" setting in the application pool
- Verify your supporting dlls e.g. "Persits ASPemail" work in Windows 2008 R2.  In some cases you may need to upgrade your license.
- Take a look at this post to assist with [SQL Server 2000 to 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50311/upgrade-sql-server-2000-database-to-2008-r2-and-enable-new-features) migration.